# Functional screening (Technology Acceptance Model)

Tags: user-research

So I have been introduced into a project with the product basically already developed. However, I am to do a functional screening survey on the product to a user pilot testing group. What does a functional screening survey look like when using the [Technology Acceptance Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_acceptance_model) as a base? Is it just a Likert scale survey?

Answer (score 2):

The TAM does use a set of category scales: 10 questions across two factors (ease of use and usefulness).

These would be implemented like any other Likert questionnaire.

Here is [a great article from MeasuringU](https://measuringu.com/usefulness/) that goes into a bit more depth on using the TAM.

EDIT:

Here are the specific Likert scale questions.

> Participants are asked to provide their level of agreement on a 7 point scale (1=strongly disagree and 7 = strongly agree). Here are the 10 usefulness items:
>
> Using this product improves the quality of the work I do.
>
> Using this product gives me greater control over my work.
>
> This product enables me to accomplish tasks more quickly.
>
> This product supports critical aspects
>
> This product increases my productivity
>
> This product improves my job performance
>
> This product allows me to accomplish more work than would otherwise be 
>   possible.
>
> This product enhances my effectiveness on the job
>
> This product makes it easier to do my job
>
> Overall, I find this product useful in my job.

Comment: If you could please copy and paste the relevant portions from the article.